# Reactjs: How to create a time picker

Tags: react-hook-form, react-datetime

I am using react-datetime for Datetime picker

But now i am looking only for time picker

Currently I use it as:

```
                  <Datetime
                    inputProps={{
                      placeholder: "HH:mm",
                      style: { height: "100%" }
                    }}
                    viewMode="time"
                    timeConstraints={{
                      hours: { min: 0, max: 6 },
                      minutes: { step: 15 }
                    }}
                  />
```

But how can I show only time picker

I am using the below currently

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-varahamihira-mo576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `dateFormat={false}` ?

```
<Datetime
dateFormat={false}
.
.
```